# Drupal as CMS / integration with existing website, menu path problems

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have website built on Zend Framework (which is not of much relevance with the problem) and **Drupal installed in subfolder / drupal**.

In root of website I have following .htaccess

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On

# this will be handled with Drupal
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog.*$  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/financing.*$  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/marketing.*$
RewriteRule (^.*$) /drupal/index.php?q=$1 [L]


# this is handled with Zend Framework
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I have idea that goes like this: If someone access www.example.com/some-url then Zend Framework or static file will be handled, but when www.example.com/blog/some-blog-post, this will handled with drupal and for that part, everything is ok.

1) Problem with drupal links is that their absolute path is www.example.com/drupal/blog/some-blog-post (of course, alias to that post is **blog/some-blog-post**, but because drupal is installed in subfolder, it adds **/drupal** before **blog/some-blog-post**). Because of .htaccess rules that are in root folder of website, following url is also valid www.example.com/blog/some-blog-post. I want to somehow remove **/drupal** part from url. How can I accomplish this ?

2) How can I link to pages that are outside /drupal folder, with relative paths, for example **/some-folder/some-page.html**, and also root of website **/** ? I know that I can link them with absolute URL, like www.example.com/some-folder/some-page.html, but that is not good for me.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal uses [base_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/base_path/6) to get that path, you can influence that with the $base_url variable in settings.php, that file contains documentation about how to do that.

Comment: When I set $base_url = "" in settings.php, I have all kind of weird problems. Can this be achieved in some other fashion: like ... Can I rewrite URLs in all links that contains words 'blog', 'financing', 'marketing' to exclude /drupal part where Drupal is installed? If you can tell me how can it be done because I'm not very good with drupal. Some hook, module, etc... ?

Comment: Note that you are setting the $base_URL, noth path. So you need to set it to something like 'http//example.org/'. Drupal will create the $base_path based on that.